# Combinations of date ranges that covers all days of input date range

Tags: php, algorithm

I want to find all possible date ranges combination that overlaps input date range. For example if user input 2013/01/10 to 2013/01/25 and I have below date ranges:

```
2013/01/08 to 2013/01/10
2013/01/09 to 2013/01/15
2013/01/10 to 2013/01/20
2013/01/18 to 2013/01/27
2013/01/14 to 2013/01/19
2013/01/19 to 2013/01/25
2013/01/14 to 2013/01/26
2013/01/10 to 2013/01/26
```

I want to find all possible combinations of above dates that overlaps input date( 2013/01/10 to 2013/01/25 ).

two examples of date range that overlaps input date is :

```
{2013/01/09 to 2013/01/15, 2013/01/14 to 2013/01/26}
{2013/01/09 to 2013/01/15, 2013/01/14 to 2013/01/19, 2013/01/19 to 2013/01/25}
```

I don't listed all of possible date ranges that overlaps input date range!
I want to find combination of date ranges that covers all of days of input date range!, If you look at two examples I combined date ranges to covering all of days of input date!
I don't want to check one date with input date range two find that if date range covers all of days of input date or no!, I want to combine date ranges to finding all of possible date ranges combinations that covers all of days of input date range.
I want an algorithm for finding all possible combinations of dates that covers all days of input date range. 
Is there any fast algorithm that solve this problem?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Sounds like an appropriate use case for interval trees to me.

Comment: Why is `2013/01/10 to 2013/01/20` missing from the list ???

Comment: @Baba - I think those are just examples and don't include all of them. Notice that 14 to 26 is on the list, which extends past the 25th. Therefore, the only one that might not qualify is is 8 to 10, but that depends on the definition of an overlap. If a meeting ends on the 10th, and Joe showed up on the 10th at the last minute of the meeting, is that an overlap?

Comment: @Baba Because I don't listed all of possible date ranges that overlaps input  date range. I only give two example of date ranges that overlaps input date range.

Comment: Dears please read my edited post, your's code loops all date ranges and find date ranges that overlaps input date but i want to find combinations of date ranges that covers all of input date range days.  excuse me for my unclear question.

Comment: I just saw your message today explaining the question, so I updated my answer. That turned out to be pretty challenging question.

Answer (score 1):

Am not really sure why `2013-01-09 to 2013-01-15` is missing from the list if you can find `2013-01-09 to 2013-01-15` but you can modify this class below as desired

```
$range = [
        new DateManager("2013/01/08", "2013/01/10"),
        new DateManager("2013/01/09", "2013/01/15"),
        new DateManager("2013/01/10", "2013/01/20"),
        new DateManager("2013/01/18", "2013/01/27"),
        new DateManager("2013/01/14", "2013/01/19"),
        new DateManager("2013/01/19", "2013/01/25"),
        new DateManager("2013/01/14", "2013/01/26"),
        new DateManager("2013/01/10", "2013/01/26")
];

$find = new DateManager("2013/01/10", "2013/01/25");

foreach($range as $date) {
    $find->overlap($date) && print($date->getRange() . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Output

```
2013/01/09 to 2013/01/15 
2013/01/10 to 2013/01/20 
2013/01/14 to 2013/01/19 
2013/01/19 to 2013/01/25
```

Class

```
class DateManager {
    private $start, $end;

    function __construct($start, $end, $format = "Y/m/d") {
        $this->start = $start instanceof DateTime ? $start : DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $start);
        $this->end = $end instanceof DateTime ? $end : DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $end);
    }

    function getStart() {
        return $this->start;
    }

    function getEnd() {
        return $this->end;
    }

    function getRange($format = "Y/m/d") {
        return sprintf("%s to %s ", $this->start->format($format), $this->end->format($format));
    }

    function between(DateManager $date) {
        return $date->getStart() >= $this->getStart() && $this->getEnd() <= $date->end;
    }

    function overlap(DateManager $date) {
        return (($date->getStart() >= $this->getStart() || $date->getEnd() > $this->getStart()) && $this->getEnd() >= $date->getEnd());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert both (start, end) dates to system time (started at 1/1/70, with step=1s), and thereafter - run cycle with step = 24 * 60 * 60. Decode each value to printable form, if needed.

Comment: I want to combine all of date ranges that covers all of input date range. I want to find all possible date range combinations that covers all days of input date range. Finding all possible combinations is problem of this post

Comment: for(time_t i1 = start; i1 < end; i1 += 24 * 60 * 60) for(time_t i2 = i1 + 24 * 60 * 60; i2 <= end; i2 += 24 * 60 * 60) process_interval(i1, i2);

Answer (score 0):

I added a couple more data items to make it more interesting:

```
$start = strtotime('2013/01/10');
$end = strtotime('2013/01/25');
$range[0]['start'] = "2013/01/08";
$range[0]['end'] = "2013/01/10";
$range[1]['start'] = "2013/01/09";
$range[1]['end'] = "2013/01/15";
$range[2]['start'] = "2013/01/10";
$range[2]['end'] = "2013/01/20";
$range[3]['start'] = "2013/01/18";
$range[3]['end'] = "2013/01/27";
$range[4]['start'] = "2013/01/14";
$range[4]['end'] = "2013/01/19";
$range[5]['start'] = "2013/01/19";
$range[5]['end'] = "2013/01/25";
$range[6]['start'] = "2013/01/14";
$range[6]['end'] = "2013/01/26";
$range[7]['start'] = "2013/01/10";
$range[7]['end'] = "2013/01/26";
$range[8]['start'] = "2013/01/9";
$range[8]['end'] = "2013/01/15";
$range[9]['start'] = "2013/01/13";
$range[9]['end'] = "2013/01/19";
$heads = array();
$tails = array();
$combos = array();
$h = 0;
foreach ($range as $key => $value){
    $r1 = strtotime($value['start']);
    $r2 = strtotime($value['end']);
    if ($r1 <= $start && $r2 >= $end){
        $combos[] = $key;
    } elseif($r1 <= $start && $r2 > $start) {
        $heads[$h]['r1'] = $r1;
        $heads[$h]['r2'] = $r2;
        $heads[$h]['seq'] = $key;
        $h++;
    } elseif($r1 > $start && $r1 < $end && $r1 < $r2) {
        $tails[$key]['r1'] = $r1;
        $tails[$key]['r2'] = $r2;
        $tails[$key]['seq'] = $key;
    }
}
while (count($tails) > 0){
    $heads2 = array();
    $tails2 = array();
    $h2 = 0;
    foreach ($heads as $key1 => $value1){
        foreach ($tails as $key2 => $value2){
            if (($value1['r1'] < $value2['r1']) && ($value1['r2'] >= $value2['r1']) && ($value1['r2'] < $value2['r2'])){
                $seq = $value1['seq'].':'.$value2['seq'];
                //keep tail alive, but don't change key
                $tails2[$key2]['r1'] = $value2['r1'];
                $tails2[$key2]['r2'] = $value2['r2'];
                $tails2[$key2]['seq'] = $key2;
                if ($value2['r2'] >= $end){
                    $combos[] = $seq;
                } else {
                    $heads2[$h2]['r1'] = $value1['r2'];
                    $heads2[$h2]['r2'] = $value2['r2'];
                    $heads2[$h2]['seq'] = $seq;
                    $h2++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $heads = $heads2;
    $tails = $tails2;
}
```

The array `$combos` contains a sequence of array keys seperated by colons, referencing the array keys of the original array. Here's a possible way to display the output:

```
$html = '';
foreach ($combos as $key => $value){
    $p = '<p>';
    $seqs = explode(':', $value);
    foreach ($seqs as $key2 => $value2){
        $p .= $range[$value2]['start'].' - '.$range[$value2]['end'].'; ';
    }
    $html .= substr($p, 0, -2).'</p>';
}
echo $html;
```

This displays the following:

```
2013/01/10 - 2013/01/26
2013/01/09 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/14 - 2013/01/26
2013/01/10 - 2013/01/20; 2013/01/18 - 2013/01/27
2013/01/10 - 2013/01/20; 2013/01/19 - 2013/01/25
2013/01/10 - 2013/01/20; 2013/01/14 - 2013/01/26
2013/01/9 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/14 - 2013/01/26
2013/01/09 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/14 - 2013/01/19; 2013/01/18 - 2013/01/27
2013/01/09 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/14 - 2013/01/19; 2013/01/19 - 2013/01/25
2013/01/09 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/13 - 2013/01/19; 2013/01/18 - 2013/01/27
2013/01/09 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/13 - 2013/01/19; 2013/01/19 - 2013/01/25
2013/01/9 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/14 - 2013/01/19; 2013/01/18 - 2013/01/27
2013/01/9 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/14 - 2013/01/19; 2013/01/19 - 2013/01/25
2013/01/9 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/13 - 2013/01/19; 2013/01/18 - 2013/01/27
2013/01/9 - 2013/01/15; 2013/01/13 - 2013/01/19; 2013/01/19 - 2013/01/25
```